# how to refresh the web interface after updating the AspxDataGrid.DataSource content with signalR?

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, signalr, devexpress

I am using DevExpress and i set the content of an ASPxGridView.DataSource but the web interface does not change (while debugging the content of the ASPxGridView.DataSource is updated) 
How can i bind that content to my web interface?

PS: while loading the page for the first time there is no problem (the content of the AspxGridView is binded correctly to the interface)

```
    public List<ListToShow> myListToShow = new List<ListToShow>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do some work
    signalRHub.On<List<ListToShow>("broadcastTransferUpdateMessage", 
  list => UpdateTransfer(list));

myNewGrid.DataSource = myListToShow;
myNewGrid.DataBind();
} // here i will get my list with right contnt ( no problem )

private void UpdateTransfer(List<ListToShow> transfers)
{
            int i = 0;
            foreach (ListToShow transfer in transfers)
            {
                i++;
                myListToShow[i] = transfer;
            }
            myNewGrid.DataSource = myListToShow;
            myNewGrid.DataBind();
} // here no updates on the web interface happened
```